# How to overwrite existing text file, then append to it

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I read settings from a hardware device and need to write them to a text file, one by one, one to a line. If the file already exists, the SavePanel asks if I want to overwrite it. I answer yes, but the file gets appended to.

```
- (IBAction)saveSettings:(id)sender
 {
   self.saveSettings = TRUE;
   self.firstWrite = TRUE;
   NSSavePanel *saveText    = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
   [saveText setNameFieldStringValue:@"SavedSettings.txt"];
   [saveText setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Documents"]];
   [saveText setShowsTagField:NO];
   NSInteger saveInt    = [saveText runModal];
   if(saveInt == NSModalResponseOK)
   {
     NSURL *pathURL = [saveText URL];
     self.pathName = [pathURL path];
     [self appendToFile:@"General configuration\n"];
     [self appendToFile:@"1\n"];
     [self appendToFile:@"1\n"];
     [self appendToFile:@"Configuration axis 1\n"];
     [self readMoveDelayAxis1];
   }
}

- (BOOL)appendToFile:(NSString *)strcontent;
{
  BOOL result = YES;
  NSFileHandle* fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.pathName];
if ( !fh ) 
{
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:self.pathName contents:nil attributes:nil];
  fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.pathName];
}
if ( !fh ) return NO;
@try {
  [fh seekToEndOfFile];
  self.firstWrite = FALSE;
  [fh writeData:[strcontent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    result = NO;
}
[fh closeFile];
return result;
}
```

The amended code per the answer below

```
- (IBAction)saveSettings:(id)sender
{
    self.saveSettings = TRUE;
    NSSavePanel *saveText   = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    [saveText setNameFieldStringValue:@"SavedSettings.txt"];
    [saveText setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Documents"]];
    [saveText setShowsTagField:NO];
    NSInteger saveInt   = [saveText runModal];
    if(saveInt == NSModalResponseOK)
    {
        NSURL *pathURL = [saveText URL];
        NSFileManager *filemgr;
        filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:[pathURL path]] == YES)
        {
            [filemgr removeItemAtPath:[pathURL path] error: NULL];
        }
        self.pathName = [pathURL path];
        [self appendToFile:@"General configuration\n"];
        [self appendToFile:@"1\n"];
        [self appendToFile:@"1\n"];
        [self appendToFile:@"Configuration axis 1\n"];
        [self readMoveDelayAxis1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSSavePanel` UI is just asking the user if the file should be overwritten, as with other `NSOpenPanel`/`NSSavePanel` situations it just returns the selected URL(s) to your application.

Your code needs to check if the file already exists and to truncate it if so, similarly to it already checking if the file does not exist and creating it if so.

You can use methods such as `truncateFileAtOffset:`, functions such as `ftruncate(2)`, etc.

HTH